# Logging in reactive streams

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm working on a reactive streams application using spring webflux. I have 1 single chain/pipeline of code that goes from Controller methods to Services to DAOs and returns back the response. During this pipeline I have a lot of Publishers. I would like to add logging support for the operators that are there in the pipeline. Say I have the following code,

```
public class Example {

 @Autowired
 private GreetingService gs;

 public Mono<String> getGreetingMessage(String name) {
  return Mono.just(name)
             .map(name -> {
                  log.info("Name is being converted to Uppercase");
                  return name.toUpperCase();})
             .map(name -> {
                  log.info("Name is being converted to Lowercase");
                  return name.toUpperCase();})
             .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                  log.error("Exception occured, relying on fallback value = guest");
                  return Mono.just("guest");})
             .flatMap(name -> {
              log.info("Getting greeting from greetingService");
              return gs.getGreeting(name);
              }); 
 }

}

@Service
public class GreetingService {
 public Mono<String> getGreeting(String name) {
  return Mono.just("Welcome, " + name+".");
 }
}
```

I know this a contrived example but the actual code is a lot lengthier than this with a lot of calls to different classes within the pipeline. How exactly do we perform the logging in this scenario? What is an elegant way to do logging?

Note: Since there are multiple publishers like in `flatMap`, `onErrorResume` I dont think we can use a simple `log()` because `log()` would only be applied to that particular publisher for which we use it.

PS: I have like 8 operators in each method of the services and DAO layers and I want to know when I get there is an exception, at what operator the issue came from. How can I do this? I thought I should use `log.info("Some message about what each operator is doing")` for each operator in the method which would around 8 log statements. or alternatively using multiple doOn* operators to do the same. What would a better way to log here?

Comment: ”Log()” logs all the communication between all the publishers, it wont log the values in the publishers etc. It would be much easier if you explained what it is you want to log, instead of just saying ”want to log elegantly”

Answer (score 1):

You can choose one of the logging frameworks such as `Log4J` or `Logback`.

Note that you must take care to configure the underlying logging framework to use its most asynchronous. For example, an [AsyncAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender) in Logback.

Here is `logback.xml` sample configuration that might help:

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %5p %t %c{15} - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="async" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <queueSize>10000</queueSize>
    <maxFlushTime>5000</maxFlushTime>
    <neverBlock>true</neverBlock>
</appender>

<logger name="com.my.package" level="trace"/>
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="async"/>
</root>
```

### You can use both log() and doOn* operator

`log()` will give you subscriber-level information like the `onComplete` signal, requested demand etc. On the other hand, `doOn*` operators could be used to log the actual data values, for instance:

```
Flux.from(messages)
      .doOnNext(message -> logger.trace("Sending " + message))
```

or

```
.flatMap(instance -> doNotify(event, instance))
.doOnError(ex -> logger.error("Couldn't notify for event {} ", event, ex))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here:

**1. Inlined in `map()`**

```java
return Mono.just(name)
     .map(name -> {
        logger.info("whatever");
        name.toUpperCase();
     })
     .map(name -> name.toLowerCase())
     .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.just("guest")
     .flatMap(name -> gs.getGreeting(name));
```

**2. Use `doOnNext()`**

```java
return Mono.just(name)
     .map(name -> name.toUpperCase())
     .doOnNext(logger.info("whatever"))
     .map(name -> name.toLowerCase())
     .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.just("guest")
     .flatMap(name -> gs.getGreeting(name));
```

Comment: I wouldn't use .map() just for the logging purposes though, since doOn* operators are specifically for this case. But, of course you could log anything in any operator that applies your functional method, simply by calling the logger in the method.

Comment: But using `doOnNext` Operator, the log be printed only when the uppercase conversion happens right or will it also work when `flatMap(name -> gs.getGreeting(name))` emits an `onNext` signal?

Comment: A single log will be printed for each emitted value in your reactive chain. In this case, after `.map(name -> name.toUpperCase())` operation.

Comment: Yeah. I Updated the question to make my usecase more clear. Can you please check it

Comment: You want a single log to log a line for each operation is that it? I am confused about your use case.

Comment: Not exactly. I want to know till which point the execution happened because in case of error I know what all things got executed and I can understand the flow of the code. As said in the question, we have a lot of service classes and when a request comes it can go through a lot of services, I want to know what all executed successfully, when there is an error.

Comment: Not sure how or even if that is possible. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are still figuring out how to log responses from methods. You can simply attach your operators like below and pass it on until the final subscription happens by the framework to process the final response for the client.
Sharing below how my Handler looks like. And from the handler, it goes to the RouterFunction.

```
 Mono<MyResponseObject> responseFromService = myService.getDataFromService(parameters)
            .doOnError(e -> log.error("Exception while fetching paginated response: {}", e.toString()))
            .doOnSuccess(e -> log.info("Success Response: {}", e.toString()));


    return ServerResponse.ok().body(responseFromService, MyResponseObject.class);
```

We should refrain from subscribing to any response in the service since the response is meant to be subscribed by the client only.

Similarly, if you don't have any error or success scenario, you can simply replace doOnError and doOnSuccess operators with doOnNext and log your data.

PS: Sorry if you feel my response is similar to what people has already answered. Just wanted to put it my way with a hope that it will help newbies like me.